# Oracle | query output separated with semicolons

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax-error

I am spooling to .csv files some values from an oracle table. Each value must be separated with semicolon. The query that i retrieve the data from is like this:

```
select TEST1|| ';' ||
to_char(BATCH_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')|| ';' ||
to_char(START_TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ';'||
to_char(END_TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  || ';'||
INPUT
from TEST_TABLE
where to_char(BATCH_DATE,'YYYYMM') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM')-1
and TEST1='ENGLISH'
order by TEST1,BATCH_DATE desc;
```

While this works like a charm, I would like also to have a semicolon at the end of INPUT.

I expected (and tried) something like this:

```
   select TEST1|| ';' ||
    to_char(BATCH_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')|| ';' ||
    to_char(START_TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ';'||
    to_char(END_TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  || ';'||
    INPUT  || ';'||
    from TEST_TABLE
    where to_char(BATCH_DATE,'YYYYMM') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM')-1
    and TEST1='ENGLISH'
    order by TEST1,BATCH_DATE desc;
```

But it does not work, it gives ORA-00936: missing expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a redundant concatination operator (`||`) at the end of your select list:

```
select TEST1|| ';' ||
to_char(BATCH_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')|| ';' ||
to_char(START_TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ';'||
to_char(END_TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  || ';'||
INPUT  || ';'
-- || removed ^
from TEST_TABLE
where to_char(BATCH_DATE,'YYYYMM') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM')-1
and TEST1='ENGLISH'
order by TEST1,BATCH_DATE desc;
```

By the way, you did not mention how you're doing the spooling, but if you're using SQL*Plus, you can just set the column separator instead of having to mess around with concatination:

```
-- separate columns with a semicolon  
set colsep ;

spool myfile.csv

-- Straight forward query, no concatination required:
select   TEST1,
         to_char(BATCH_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         to_char(START_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         to_char(END_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         input
  from   TEST_TABLE
  where  to_char(BATCH_DATE, 'YYYYMM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') - 1 and
         TEST1='ENGLISH'
order by TEST1, BATCH_DATE desc;

spool off
```